# return amount per year/month records based on start and enddate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a table with, for example this data:

```
ID |start_date  |end_date   |amount
---|------------|-----------|--------
1  |2019-03-21  |2019-05-09 |10000.00
2  |2019-04-02  |2019-04-10 |30000.00
3  |2018-11-01  |2019-01-08 |20000.00
```

I would like te get the splitted records back with the correct calculated amount based on the year/month.

I expect the outcome to be like this:

```
ID |month |year   |amount
---|------|-------|--------
1  |3     | 2019  | 2200.00
1  |4     | 2019  | 6000.00
1  |5     | 2019  | 1800.00
2  |4     | 2019  |30000.00
3  |11    | 2018  | 8695.65
3  |12    | 2018  | 8985.51
3  |1     | 2019  | 2318.84
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I think you would have to use DATEDIFF to get the number of days between the start_date and end_date to calculate the amount per day, but I'm not sure how to return it as records per month/year.

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Do you have a calendar table, or can you create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one idea. I use a Tally to create a day for every day the amount is relevant for for that `ID`. Then, I aggregate the value of the `Amount` divided by the numbers of days, which is grouped by Month and year:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(ID int,
                           StartDate date,
                           EndDate date,
                           Amount decimal(12,2));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID,
                           StartDate,
                           EndDate,
                           Amount)
VALUES(1,'2019-03-21','2019-05-09',10000.00),
      (2,'2019-04-02','2019-04-10',30000.00),
      (3,'2018-11-01','2019-01-08',20000.00);
GO
--Create a tally
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, t.StartDate, t.EndDate)+1) FROM dbo.YourTable t) --Limits the rows, might be needed in a large dataset, might not be, remove as required
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days, is that enough?
--Create the dates
Dates AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           DATEADD(DAY, T.I, YT.StartDate) AS [Date],
           YT.Amount,
           COUNT(T.I) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.ID) AS [Days]
    FROM Tally T
         JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, YT.StartDate, YT.EndDate))
--And now aggregate
SELECT D.ID,
       DATEPART(MONTH,D.[Date]) AS [Month],
       DATEPART(YEAR,D.[Date]) AS [Year],
       CONVERT(decimal(12,2),SUM(D.Amount / D.[Days])) AS Amount
FROM Dates D
GROUP BY D.ID,
         DATEPART(MONTH,D.[Date]),
         DATEPART(YEAR,D.[Date])
ORDER BY D.ID,
         [Year],
         [Month];

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5a360f11ac87027a2328f14ba8ab90b)

Comment: Thank you! This works superb and fast on my local DB. It loads instantly. Remote on my SQL Azure DB it takes about 10 seconds with exactly the same data. Do you have any idea how that is possible? The query returns about 9000 rows.

Comment: If it's remote it could simply be the time for you to download the dataset over the WAN. I don't know what your Up and Down speeds are like. If you `INSERT` (using an `INTO` to a temporary table if you like) the data into another table (so you don't return the dataset to yourself) if it faster by answer chance?

Comment: This seems not to be the issue. It's really the execution time of the query being massive on SQL Azure. Around 15 seconds even.

Comment: A lacl of indexing on your server in Azure? Maybe you have a very low spec Azure server, @Stackberg ? The problem appears to be the performance of the server you're using, not the SQL (which I am very confident in the performance of on a well designed database and performant instance). This will certainly significantly out perform a rCTE solution.

Comment: To make sure I have the exact same database with same indexes and same data I've extracted my Sql Azure as a data tier application and imported it locally. I have a low spec Azure server but I don't believe that would dregrade performance from instant result to 15 seconds.

Comment: I can only suggest that it is the Azure server that is struggling, @Stackberg, and this wasn't a question about how can you make an Azure Server perform faster. Even a small Server I have access to (with a Gen 6 dual core i3 and only access to 1Mbps UP) returns a dataset of 32,400 rows in 8 seconds (and the bottle neck is the upload, as it does it in 3 seconds with an `INTO` clause). I very much suggest that a lack of power on the host, and the fact the data needs to be streamed over the WAN makes a combined result of "slowness" (and why i suggested an `INTO` clause to check if it is the WAN).

Comment: It seems like SQL Azure has problems with queyr's using the with-statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333477/sql-azure-very-slow-performance-on-with-statement-query 
Do you have any idea on how to rewrite the above in a decent way to test is that's the case?

Comment: That is a "decent" way, @Stackberg. Tally tables are incredibly efficient. [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

Comment: I know a Tally table is incredibly efficient but its seems a bug in SQL Azure keeps query's containing a WITH-statement from permorming. See the link in my comment above.

Comment: Ok this is what i found out: There are 226282 records in my tally.

It's only this part that takes 15 seconds.
   SELECT YT.ID,
    DATEADD(DAY, T.I, YT.StartDate) AS [Date], YT.Amount,
    COUNT(T.I) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.ID) AS [Days]
    FROM Tally T
    JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, YT.StartDate, YT.EndDate)

There are many unneeded records in the Tally. You would only need start and enddates of a period and the start and enddates of the months that the period spans

Comment: Where are there uneeded **rows** @Stackberg? It only creates a row when a date in the range; as are all "needed".

Comment: I was thinking it wrongly. Thanks for the help. If I would want to union the results of the query would that be possible?

Comment: yes, just put a `UNION{ ALL}` after it; like any other query.