# Split amount per date-range into amount per month/year

Tags: c#, linq, date-range

I'm basicly trying to do the same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991290/return-amount-per-year-month-records-based-on-start-and-enddate) only I want to do this in C# and not in SQL.

I have a class:

```
public class AmountPerPeriod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Enddate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

For this example say I populate a list of `AmountPerPeriod` items with:

```
var lstAmountPerPeriod = new List<AmountPerPeriod>()
            {
                new AmountPerPeriod
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Startdate = new DateTime(2019, 03, 21),
                    Enddate = new DateTime(2019, 05, 09),
                    Amount = 10000
                },
                new AmountPerPeriod
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Startdate = new DateTime(2019, 04, 02),
                    Enddate = new DateTime(2019, 04, 10),
                    Amount = 30000
                },
                new AmountPerPeriod
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Startdate = new DateTime(2018, 11, 01),
                    Enddate = new DateTime(2019, 01, 08),
                    Amount = 20000
                }
            };
```

I want my out put to be a List of AmountPerMonth class which looks like this:

```
public class AmountPerMonth
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Like I should I tried and I got a working method which I feel its way way way to complex. This method which provided the correct outcome looks like this:

```
var result = new List<AmountPerMonth>();

    foreach (var item in lstAmountPerPeriod)
    {
        if (item.Startdate.Year == item.Enddate.Year && item.Startdate.Month == item.Enddate.Month)
        {
            result.Add(new AmountPerMonth
            {
                Amount = item.Amount,
                Id = item.Id,
                Month = item.Startdate.Month,
                Year = item.Startdate.Year
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var numberOfDaysInPeriod = (item.Enddate - item.Startdate).Days+1;
            var amountPerDay = item.Amount / numberOfDaysInPeriod;
            var periodStartDate = item.Startdate;

            bool firstPeriod = true;

            while (periodStartDate.ToFirstDateOfMonth() <= item.Enddate.ToFirstDateOfMonth())
            {
                if (firstPeriod)
                {
                    result.Add(new AmountPerMonth
                    {
                        Amount = ((periodStartDate.ToLastDateOfMonth()-periodStartDate).Days+1)*amountPerDay,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        Month = periodStartDate.Month,
                        Year = periodStartDate.Year
                    });
                }
                else if (periodStartDate.Month != item.Enddate.Month)
                {
                    result.Add(new AmountPerMonth
                    {
                        Amount = ((periodStartDate.ToLastDateOfMonth()-periodStartDate.ToFirstDateOfMonth()).Days+1) * amountPerDay,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        Month = periodStartDate.Month,
                        Year = periodStartDate.Year
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(new AmountPerMonth
                    {
                        Amount = ((item.Enddate - periodStartDate.ToFirstDateOfMonth()).Days+1) * amountPerDay,
                        Id = item.Id,
                        Month = periodStartDate.Month,
                        Year = periodStartDate.Year
                    });
                }

                periodStartDate = periodStartDate.AddMonths(1);

                firstPeriod = false;
            }
        }
    }


// assert using fluentassertions
result.Count.Should().Be(7);
result.First().Amount.Should().Be(2200);
result.Last().Amount.Should().BeApproximately(2318.84M, 2);

// list with result basically should contain:
// ID |month |year   |amount
// ---|------|-------|--------
// 1  |3     | 2019  | 2200.00
// 1  |4     | 2019  | 6000.00
// 1  |5     | 2019  | 1800.00
// 2  |4     | 2019  |30000.00
// 3  |11    | 2018  | 8695.65
// 3  |12    | 2018  | 8985.51
// 3  |1     | 2019  | 2318.84
```

Like I said there should be a much easier way, even possibly using LINQ. Anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have some extension methods in play here. I assume `ToFirstDateOfMonth` only modifies the day to `1`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it, the basic difference here is that I'm using a `for` loop to continually update the "first day" to either the first day in the period or the first day of the current month, and the "last day" to either the last day of the current month or the last day of the period, whichever is smaller.

I also added this as a static method on the `AmountPerMonth` class, which takes in an `AmountPerPeriod` and returns a `List<AmountPerMonth>`. Additionally, I overrode the `ToString` method to output a string similar to the one in your question, so the output looks the same:

```
public class AmountPerMonth
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public static List<AmountPerMonth> FromPeriod(AmountPerPeriod period)
    {
        if (period == null) return null;
        var amtPerDay = period.Amount / ((period.EndDate - period.StartDate).Days + 1);
        var result = new List<AmountPerMonth>();

        for (var date = period.StartDate; date <= period.EndDate; 
             date = date.AddMonths(1).ToFirstDateOfMonth())
        {
            var lastDayOfMonth = date.ToLastDateOfMonth();
            var lastDay = period.EndDate < lastDayOfMonth
                ? period.EndDate
                : lastDayOfMonth;
            var amount = ((lastDay - date).Days + 1) * amtPerDay;

            result.Add(new AmountPerMonth
            {
                Id = period.Id,
                Year = date.Year,
                Month = date.Month,
                Amount = amount
            });
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id,-3} |{Month,-6}| {Year,-6}| {Amount:0.00}";
    }
}
```

We can use this method as an argument to `SelectMany` from your sample data to generate our list and output the results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lstAmountPerPeriod = new List<AmountPerPeriod>()
    {
        new AmountPerPeriod
        {
            Id = 1,
            StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 03, 21),
            EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 05, 09),
            Amount = 10000
        },
        new AmountPerPeriod
        {
            Id = 2,
            StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 04, 02),
            EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 04, 10),
            Amount = 30000
        },
        new AmountPerPeriod
        {
            Id = 3,
            StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 11, 01),
            EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 01, 08),
            Amount = 20000
        }
    };

    var amountsPerMonth = lstAmountPerPeriod.SelectMany(AmountPerMonth.FromPeriod);

    Console.WriteLine("ID |month |year   |amount");
    Console.WriteLine("---|------|-------|--------");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, amountsPerMonth));

    GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Note: These extension methods were used in the code above:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime ToFirstDateOfMonth(this DateTime input)
    {
        return new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, 1, input.Hour, 
            input.Minute, input.Second, input.Millisecond, input.Kind);
    }

    public static DateTime ToLastDateOfMonth(this DateTime input)
    {
        return new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, 
            DateTime.DaysInMonth(input.Year, input.Month), input.Hour,
            input.Minute, input.Second, input.Millisecond, input.Kind);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier with LINQ.

```
var output =
    from app in lstAmountPerPeriod
    let days = (int)app.Enddate.Date.Subtract(app.Startdate.Date).TotalDays + 1
    from day in Enumerable.Range(0, days)
    let daily = new AmountPerPeriod()
    {
        Id = app.Id,
        Startdate = app.Startdate.AddDays(day),
        Enddate = app.Startdate.AddDays(day),
        Amount = app.Amount / days
    }
    group daily.Amount by new
    {
        daily.Id,
        daily.Startdate.Year,
        daily.Startdate.Month
    } into gds
    select new AmountPerMonth()
    {
        Id = gds.Key.Id,
        Year = gds.Key.Year,
        Month = gds.Key.Month,
        Amount = gds.Sum(),
    };
```

This query returns:

[image: output]

Comment: I cannot stop thinking that there is a solution that doesn't require calculating a daily value and looks as good as this. Anyway, this answer is a beauty.

Comment: Thanks! Aesthetically this solution is beautiful! You'll get a vote up from me for that! However, performance wise the solution provided by @RufusL is much better so I'm going to accept that as the answer

Comment: @Stackberg - Why is performance an issue? That wasn't specified in the question. You did ask for "a much easier way". Isn't this a much easier way?

Comment: @Enigmativity In my opinion performance is always an issue, but I will mention it clearly next time. Thanks for the feedback, I honesty appreciate it.